# Registro de usuários no WordPress com formulário personalizado

Tags: php, wordpress

Tenho um formulário de cadastro de usuário dentro do meu shortcode.

Código completo

```
     <?php
         $user_login_RU = $_POST['username_RU'];
         $user_email_RU= $_POST['email_RU'];
            if(isset($user_login_RU, $user_email_RU)){
               $teste = register_new_user($user_login, $user_email);
               if ( !is_wp_error($teste) ) {
                  $redirect_to = !empty( $_POST['redirect_to'] ) ? $_POST['redirect_to'] : 'wp-login.php?checkemail=registered';
            wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_to );
            }

        //register meta values
          register_users_save_dados( $id_new_user, $_POST);
    }

      function register_users_shortcode(){
       global $post;
     ?>
        <div id="form1">
           <form id="form1" name="form1"action="" method="POST" ectype="multipart/form-data">
             <p>
                <label for="nome_RU">Username:</label>
                <br />
                <input type="text" name="username_RU" id="username_RU" value="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_username_RU', true ); ?>" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="email_RU">E-mail:</label>
                <br />
                <input type="email" name="email_RU" id="email_RU"value="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_email_RU', true ); ?>" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <h2>Tipo de cadastro</h2>
                    Empregador <input type="radio" name="type_user" onclick="document.getElementById('empregador').style.display = 'block'; document.getElementById('trabalhador').style.display = 'none'"value="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_empregador', true ); ?>">
                    Trabalhador <input type="radio" name="type_user" onclick="document.getElementById('empregador').style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById('trabalhador').style.display = 'block'"value="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_Empregador', true ); ?>">
            </p>
            <div id="empregador" style="display:none">
                <h3>Identificação do empregador</h3>
                    <strong>*Tipo de indentificação:</strong><br />
                        <?php echo register_render("tipo_id_empregador", "radio","tipo_id_empregador" ,array("CNPJ","CPF","CEI")); ?><br />
                    <strong>*Número de indentificação:</strong>
                        <?php echo register_render('numeroIdEmpregador','text'); ?>
                <h3>Dados referente ao empregador</a></h3>
                    <strong>*Razão social:</strong> 
                        <?php echo register_render('razaoSocialEmpregador','text'); ?>
                    <strong>*Nome fantasia:</strong>
                        <?php echo register_render('nomeFantasiaEmpregador','text'); ?>

                <h3>Localização da empresa</h3>
                    <strong>*Logradouro:</strong>
                        <?php echo register_render('logradouroEmpregador','text'); ?>
                <br />
            </div>

            <div id="trabalhador" style="display:none">
                <h3>Indentificação do Trabalhador</h3>
                    <strong>*Número de Indentificação (PIS/PASEP/NIS/NIT)</strong>
                        <?php echo register_render('numeroIdTralhador','text'); ?> <br />
                    <strong>*Nome da mãe do trabalhador</strong>
                        <?php echo register_render('maeTrabalhador','text'); ?>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="sub" value="cadastrar">
        </form>
    </div>
        <?php }

    add_shortcode('my-form','register_users_shortcode');
```

função para salvar os inputs dinâmicos

```
      function register_users_save_dados( $id_register_users,$value) {
         foreach ($value as $key) {
            if(isset($_POST[$key]))
                add_post_meta( $id_register_users, '_$key', strip_tags( $_POST[$key] ) );
    }
}
```

mais não consigo registrar um novo usuário, vem o seguinte erro de log:

> Call to undefined function `get_user_by()`

Comment: Any, por favor, organize seu código de forma lógica. Fica mais fácil para você encontrar os problemas por si mesma, e quem fôr te ajudar vai ler o código rapidamente sem perder tempo decifrando o fluxo das coisas.

Comment: Por favor, edite a Pergunta, o campo de Respostas é para ***soluções***. . . . . Você não disse onde estão localizados seus códigos, qual arquivo? É o mesmo? . . . Dica: você está programando sem ter o `WP_DEBUG` ligado, isso mostra pequenos erros do programa (tipo `$var = $_POST['NOME']`, isso solta uma *notice* e deve ser evitada): http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: Nunca usei o wp_debug, obg por essa dica.

Comment: Você ainda não disse onde está esse código. Que arquivo?

Comment: Está dentro de uma pasta chamada shortcodes, dentro da pasta do meu plugin, o da função está em outra pasta chamada funções, e ambos são chamados na minha pasta raiz onde defino o nome do meu plugin.

Comment: Pois é, sem ter um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) do seu código fica difícil responder. Sinto muito.

Answer (score 3):

Seu problema está em *"redireciona para a seguinte página em PHP"*. Certamente você fez uma página independente que está fora do escopo do WordPress e não reconhece suas funções.

Segue um exemplo demonstrativo de como fazer usando a mesma página onde o shortcode é impresso. Note o [uso do `nonce` para validar a requisão do form](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field). É **essencial** usar nomes personalizados no form, `name="my-msg"`, isso evita conflitos com variáveis do próprio WP.

```
add_shortcode( 'my-form', function() {
    global $post;
    $nonce = wp_nonce_field( 'sopt_35412', 'sopt_35412', true, false ); // false == não faz echo
    // Sintaxe Heredoc
    // http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc
    $form = <<<HTML
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
        $nonce
        <label>Sua mensagem
            <input type="text" name="my-msg" id="msg" />
        </label>
        <p>
        <label>Submit
            <input type="submit" name="my-submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
        </label>
        </p>
    </form>
HTML;

    if( wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['sopt_35412'], 'sopt_35412' ) && isset( $_POST["my-submit"] ) ) {
        $form = $form . sopt_acessivel();
    } else if( isset( $_POST["my-submit"] ) ) { // Só para testar o nonce, troque o nome do nonce no form para ver o efeito 
        $form = $form . '<h1 style="color:#f00">ERRO DE SEGURANÇA</h1>';
    }
    return $form;
});

function sopt_acessivel() {
    return sprintf( '<h3>Postou msg:</h3><p>%s</p>', $_POST["my-msg"] );
}
```

Comment: De interesse: [*How to Use AJAX in a WordPress Shortcode?*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13614297/1287812) & [*Make plugin override template*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13999632/1287812)

Comment: está na mesma página do shortcode agora e dá a mesma coisa.

Comment: vou organizar melhor

Comment: Testou meu código? Qual a diferença dele pro seu? Você não mostra seu shortcode, só uns pedaços de código solto...

Comment: Vou mostrar o meu shortcode